# NullPointerException at android.widget.AbsListView.contentFits(AbsListView.java:722)

Tags: java, android-listview, nullpointerexception, android

I get a strange `NullPointerException`. There is no pointing in my code. Also I know that my app gives this NullPointerException only on:

**Manufacturer : Sony Ericsson

Product : MT11i_1256-3856

Android-version : 2.3.4**

Any ideas?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.widget.AbsListView.contentFits(AbsListView.java:722)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:2430)
    at android.widget.ListView.onTouchEvent(ListView.java:3447)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3952)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:995)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1034)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1034)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1034)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1034)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1711)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1145)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2096)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1695)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2217)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1901)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have lots of similar exceptions in our apps. I did some research in Android OS source code, and made a conclusion - this is bug of Android OS Gingerbread and below, and it has been fixed in Ice Cream Sandwich.

If you want more details, look at source code of method [`AbsListView.contentFits`](http://androidxref.com/2.3.6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/AbsListView.java) in Gingerbread source tree:

```
private boolean contentFits() {
    final int childCount = getChildCount();
    if (childCount != mItemCount) {
        return false;
    }

    return getChildAt(0).getTop() >= 0 && getChildAt(childCount - 1).getBottom() <= mBottom;
}
```

It's obvious that this method will throw `NullPointerException` if called for empty list, because `getChildAt(0)` will return NULL. This was fixed in [ICS source tree](http://androidxref.com/4.1.1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/AbsListView.java)

```
private boolean contentFits() {
    final int childCount = getChildCount();
    if (childCount == 0) return true;
    if (childCount != mItemCount) return false;

    return getChildAt(0).getTop() >= mListPadding.top &&
            getChildAt(childCount - 1).getBottom() <= getHeight() - mListPadding.bottom;
}
```

As you can see, there is a check for `(childCount == 0)`.

Regarding a **workaround** for this issue - you can declare your own class `MyListView extends ListView`, override method `onTouchEvent` and surround call to `super.onTouchEvent()` with a try-catch block. Of course you will need to use your custom ListView class in all places in your app.